# how to display a table based on a column value (CSV Path)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a table as such

| File Name | File path |
| --- | --- |
| MyFile1.csv | D:\tmp\MyFile1.csv |
| MyFile2.csv | D:\tmp\MyFile1.csv |

So Far , i'm displaying my **main table** as such

```html
 <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
                            <thead>
                                <tr style="background-color:#555;color:white;">
                                    <th>File Name</th>
                                    <th>File path</th>
                                    

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                $query_table = "select File_Name as File_Name,  file_path  as file_path  from table_logs ";
                                $result_table = pg_query($dbconn1, $query_table) or die('Échec de la requête : ' . pg_last_error());

                                while ($list_table = pg_fetch_assoc($result_table)) {
                                    echo '<tr><td>' . $list_table['File_Name '] . '</td><td>' .  $list_table['file_path  ']   . '</td></tr>';
                                }


                                ?>

                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                     <th>File Name</th>
                                    <th>File path</th>


                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
</div>
```

To access the csv files a transform them dynamicaly to **sub tables**  based on the **file paths** i'm using this php code and that working fine

```
<?php
    $query_table = "select File_Name as File_Name,  file_path  as file_path  from table_logs";
    $result_table = pg_query($dbconn1, $query_table) or die('Échec de la requête : ' . pg_last_error());

    while ($list_table = pg_fetch_assoc($result_table)) {

        echo "<br><html><body><table  >\n\n";
        $f = fopen($list_table['file_path'], "r");
        while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        fclose($f);
        echo "\n</table></body></html>";
    }


    ?>
```

My output is as such for the  file path 1 :     D:\tmp\MyFile1.csv

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | value1 |
| key2 | value2 |

My output is as such for the  file path 2 :     D:\tmp\MyFile2.csv

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | my row 1 |
| key2 | my row 2 |

My question is how display a table when clicking on the value of a **File Path**

Do i have to add a button the main table ?

How could i achieve the link between the main table and the sub tables ?

How to use ajax to pass the variable and display in Javascript the result ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anchor tag for that and pass the filename with your link than grab it from the URL and show data of that file. You can get your filename when people click on your file paths.

```
    <a href="?fileanme=MyFile2">D:\tmp\MyFile1.csv</a> 
    <br> 
    <?php echo isset($_GET['fileanme']) && $_GET['fileanme'] ? $_GET['fileanme'] : '' ?>
```

Comment: Not working and don't fit the requirement . Thanks